# I wrote several dataframes to excel woorkbook using ExcelWriter. But I dont know where they saved to

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I recently wrote a script to write excel files using ExcelWriter from python. The code executes successfully but I dont know where the file saved to? Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

````
right_advcorp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="AdvisorCorporation")

right_branchname.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="BranchName")

right_branchcode.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="BranchCode")

right_partyid.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="PartyId")

right_retailmga.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="RetailMgaFirm")

right_sellingcode.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="SellingCode")

df6.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="AdvisorEntityNC_AdvisorNCName")

writer.save()```
````

Comment: How did you initialize your `writer`?

Comment: Mostly it will be saving to the `dir` where your are running your code from.

Comment: Found it! Thank you. It was int he working directory